# What happens if you use @reboot reboot in crontab file?

Tags: sudo, cron, reboot

What would happen if you use:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

And add the line:

```
@reboot reboot
```

Will it go into a infinite loop of rebooting?!

Comment: let's test it :)

Comment: Why not? Do you think the `reboot` command is special?

Comment: If not, it's a bug ;-)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Testing result:

If you add

```
@reboot reboot
```

This did not work!!! Why?

```
$ which reboot
/sbin/reboot
```

Now When i added the full path of reboot, the cron job runs normally.

So you got an infinite  loop of rebooting in the case:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

And add the line:

```
@reboot /sbin/reboot
```

---

EDIT:

If you want to get rid off this, you probably need to boot from an Live CD, then mount your disk drive and go to the `cron` file and remove the added line.

```
sudo gedit /media/some-UUID/var/spool/cron/crontabs/root
```

Save and then remove livecd and reboot again, and you'll be safe

Comment: Just for the extra service we always provide: it would be nice to include a method where you can remove this alteration ;)

Comment: Yea, that would be the next question! If you do this, how can you gain back control?

Comment: @Rinzwind Ok i'll do that

Comment: Good one. I always said CS is an experimental science. ;-)

Comment: @Maythux should also be possible from grub (drop to console mode and nano it out of tje crontab ;) )

Comment: @Rinzwind There are many other rescue tools, i just stated one of them, but also you can use some rescue cd, the recovery mode, ....

Comment: For the OP, remember that you can safely test these things in a VM (virtual machine), e.g. VirtualBox.